Past participle of adjectives—sometimes, sometimes not
My question is how to know when to use the past participle in an adjective and when to not. For example, why is the first bullet "tone" instead "toned" if the second is "plated" instead of "plate":

"She wore gold-tone bracelets."
"She wore gold-plated bracelets."

I don't quite understand the nuance in the meaning between the two—why wouldn't the gold bracelet be toned? According to Merriam-Webster, toned is "characterized or distinguished by a tone"...so isn't the bracelet "characterized or distinguished" by being gold toned?
Thank you in advance!

The gold color bracelet looks similar to gold. Just a static fact. The one that underwent a gold bath treatment was actively plated. One looks like gold, the other was acted upon.

@YosefBaskin hmm, I do see what you're saying. So what if tone/toned were replaced with color/colored—"gold-colored bracelets" or "gold-color bracelets"? To me, gold-color seems strange because they've been colored gold. But if that's true, how is their action of being colored any different than their action of being toned?

"how to know"—as with many things, less by following a formula than simply by being accustomed to idiomatic (and yes, idiosyncratic) custom.

But no, there is more to it. "Color" works both ways; "it has been colored gold" or "its color is gold." You can't do the same with "plate;" you can't say "its plate is gold." You can't use the non-participle with something that can't be an attribute.

"Tone" is a noun there, similar to "gold-colour bracelet". Although you could also say "gold-coloured bracelet" with a past participle. You could also say "gold-plate bracelets", meaning bracelets made of gold plate. I'm sure there are existing questions about similar constructions, but there's a lot of freedom.
